# Normal Subgroup of index 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $N\trianglelefteq G$ with $[G:N]=4$. Show that there is an $N'\trianglelefteq G$ with $[G:N']=2$.

Proof. We have $|G/N|=4$, so there must exist a $M\trianglelefteq G/N$ of order 2. This corresponds to a $N'\trianglelefteq G$ with $N\subseteq N'$. We now have $4=[G:N]=[G:N']\cdot[N':N]$. How can I obtain $[N':N]=2$ from $|M|=2$?

Comment: Perhaps you should highlight more precisely where the gap is present.  You could appeal (for example) to the Third Isomorphism Thm. for some of the last step.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834137/if-a-group-doesnt-have-subgroups-of-index-2-and-3-then-any-subgroup-of-index-4). Don Antonio also answered your question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by highlighting where the gap is present. My gap is that I cannot conclude $[N':N]=2$. I already used the isomoprhism theorem $G/N\cong (G/N')/(N'/N)$ to get the formula for the indices.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't understand the immediate equivalence he doesn't bother to prove.

Comment: He does. He writes $M$ as quotient modulo $N$, and then uses the correspondence theorem.

Comment: So in my case $M\cong N'/N$? How do I verify this?

Comment: You need to show that $N \neq N' \neq G$ and then consider the factors of 4.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|M|$ =2, $M$ has $2$ cosets $N$ and $gN$ where $g\in G - N$. Thus $N'= N\cup gN$ so $[N':N]=2$

Comment: I don't understand how we get to $N'=N\cup gN$. You are using the correspondence theorem, aren't you? In which way does the bijective map obtain order? I don't know of any proof or theorem that makes a statement about this.

Comment: What do you think $G/N$ is? It is the set of 4 cosets of $N$ in $G$. They form a group of order 4 (since there are exactly four of them) using the multiplication they inherit from $G$. If $M$ is a subgroup of order 2 of $G/N$, then  $M$ must consist of two of the four cosets that make up $G/N$ one of which is $N$ itself which acts as the identity.  To show that the union of the two cosets form a subgroup $N'$ of G you need to show that if $a$ and $b$ are in the union then $ab$ is also. This can be divided into cases: both $a$ and $b$ are in $N$, one is in $N$, and neither is.